# Javascript; push an array object into another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I am writing an application to calculate genetic crosses with punnett squares, my app allows the user to specify how many trait crosses they'd like to calculate up to 5, so the ambiguity in my code is ever-growing.. and I am a bit lost on this one strange javascript nuance I'm seeing

```
var traitSchema = {
  "traitName" : '',
  "dominant" : false,
  "alleles" : ['','']
};

self.parent1 = {
  "traits": []
}

self.parent2 = {
  "traits": []
}
```

//OTHER CODE //

```
// Called by init (onchage traitsnum); populates traits array according to traitsnum

function buildParents() {
  for(var i = 0; i < self.traitsNum; i++) {
    self.parent1.traits.push(angular.copy(traitSchema));
    self.parent2.traits.push(angular.copy(traitSchema));
  }
}

self.submitClick = function() {
  if ((self.traitsNum < 1) || (self.traitsNum > 5)) {
    alert("You must choose 1 to 5 traits to calculate.");
  }
  else {
    assignAllelesCross();
  }
};

function assignAllelesCross() {
  var parent1Alleles = [];
  var parent2Alleles = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < self.traitsNum; i++) {
    parent1Alleles.push(self.parent1.traits[i].alleles);
    parent2Alleles.push(self.parent2.traits[i].alleles);

  }

  console.log('parent 1 alleles ' + parent1Alleles);
  console.log('parent 2 alleles ' + parent2Alleles)
}
```

So everything is working alright but the results displayed in my console for parents trait1 and trait2 alleles looks like this --> [A,a,B,b]

But what I need is --> [[A,a], [B,b]]

I am not exactly sure what it is that is causing it to split out into every individual value, rather than keeping the original allele array objects as their own array object the way it's specified in the schema declaration.

Framework Info:
    angular": 1.5.7

Any help is much appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: console.log deals with strings in your case because you have `'string' + array'` - so, what you are seeing is the string version of parent1Alleles and parent2Alleles ... try `console.log('parent 1 alleles ' + JSON.stringify(parent1Alleles))`

Comment: alternatively `console.log('parent 1 alleles', parent1Alleles);`

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like:

`console.log('parent 1 alleles ' + parent1Alleles);`

the `parent1Alleles` gets converted to string using toString() method. For arrays, toString() internally calls toString() of each elements and appends them separated by a comma (,). Since the individual elements are also arrays, the end result looks like a flat array of four elements.

You can get the desired output, if you consider your array as a JSON, and stringify it properly before appending it to string. Something like this should work:

`console.log('parent 1 alleles ' + JSON.stringify(parent1Alleles));`